# Overloaded operator<< for ostream syntax

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, ostream

I hav been going over some old hw assignments from a class last semester.
This was a given print function to print out linked list objects.
I don't understand why the overloaded operator takes two parameters and one being an
os object. When we were printing out actual linked list objects on main.cpp, we didn't
need to pass an os object. Also, why is it returning os? Why can't we just use cout
instead of "os <<" ?

Thank you!

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::print(ostream & os) const
{
    os << "<";
    ListNode * curr = head;
    while (curr != NULL) {
        os << " " << curr->data;
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    os << " >";
}



// overloaded operator<<
template <class T>
ostream & operator<<(ostream & os, const List<T> & list)
{
    list.print(os);
    return os;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the way the question was asked and how basic it is, I'm going to try to give a very simplistic (albeit rather informal and not so pedantic) answer.

> I don't understand why the overloaded operator takes two parameters
>   and one being an os object

operator<< is a binary operator. It has a left-hand side and a right-hand side. When you write:

```
cout << 123;
```

You are invoking this operator with two operands (arguments): 'cout' on the left and an integer, '123', on the right.

> When we were printing out actual linked list objects on main.cpp, we
>   didn't need to pass an os object.

Your print function is a member function or operator of a class. That would implicitly deduce that the first argument, crudely speaking, does not need to be explicitly passed since you already have the 'this' pointer to work with for your list object. That's not the case with non-member operators as you don't have an implicitly deduced 'this' object to work with already for the left-hand side operand.

When you write code like this:

```
my_list.print(cout);
```

You can think of it as actually passing in two arguments, 'my_list' and 'cout'. Even though you don't write it explicitly, you have access to 'my_list' through 'this' along with its members. That's not the case if you wrote the print function as a non-member, like so:

```
template <class T>
void print(const List<T>& my_list, ostream& os);
```

That's also the case with your operator which is not a member function.

> Also, why is it returning os?

Returning a reference to ostream is what allows us to write statements like this:

```
cout << "hello " << "world";
```

First we invoke operator<<(cout, "hello ") which then gives us another ostream reference to work with which then allows us to proceed to invoke operator<<(cout, "world"). If it returned void, for example, it would not allow us to invoke that operator twice in one statement since we'd be trying to output "world " with void as the left-hand operand.

> Why can't we just use cout instead of "os <<" ?

cout basically implements the ostream interface. So does ofstream, ostringstream, and other types of output streams. By writing it in terms of the basic *interface* required and not some specific ostream derivative, you allow the code you write to work with stdio streams, file streams, stream streams, and others. Basically it makes your code very general and reusable which is something you should strive to do when practical. You'll learn about this subject more as you tackle the concept of polymorphism.

Comment: "stream streams"?  Is that a typo for "string streams"?

Answer (score 2):

Because it is a global non-member function. With the member function version, the first parameter is implicitly the invoking object, `this`. That means that your class always has to be on the left hand side. With the non-member function, it's an explicit parameter; this way, you can specify any type you want, and overload operators for classes that you can't modify the source for (as long as at least one parameter is a user-defined type).

The reason why you use `os` is so that it works with file streams and everything (anything that inherits from `ostream`), instead of just `cout`.

It returns `os` so that you can do more `operator<<` calls on the return value. This enables operator chaining, like `w << x << y << z`, which is the same as `operator<<(operator<<(operator<<(w, x), y), z)`. If you return `void` or something, you would have to stop at `w << x` because you can't do anything with the return value of `void`.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why the overloaded operator takes two parameters and one being an os object. When we were printing out actual linked list objects on main.cpp, we didn't need to pass an os object.

Yes you did: when you say `cout << x`, you are passing `cout` and `x` to `operator<<`.

> Also, why is it returning os?

To make `cout << x << y` possible. This is parsed as `(cout << x) << y`, i.e. it inserts `y` into the return value of `cout << x`.

> Why can't we just use cout instead of "os <<" ?

Because sometimes you want to output to another stream than standard output.

Answer (score 0):

> When we were printing out actual linked list objects on main.cpp, we
>   didn't need to pass an os object.

Yes, you did.. something like `cout << obj;`, where cout is the `os` output stream.

> > Also, why is it returning os? Why can't we just use cout instead of "os <<" ?

This allows chaining: `cout << obj << " " << obj2;`

> > Why can't we just use cout instead of "os <<" ?

That would hard-wire the output stream, so you couldn't write to file or any other output.